# Creating CSV files Android

Tags: java, android, file, csv, android-studio

Trying to have a folder of CSV files in my android studio project. 
A CSV file is created when a user presses a button and then put in that folder in my project, however, I keep getting a 'file doesn't exist error' and am unsure why. i added this is my android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here is how i am calling my Logger object

```
 startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String timeOpened = new Date().toString();
                Logger logger;
                Context c = getApplicationContext();
                try {
                    logger = new Logger(timeOpened, c);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });
```

And here is my class where I am trying to create a new CSV file in my log_CSV folder

```
public class Logger {
    public Logger(String name, Context ctx) {
        File f = new File("/Users/G/Desktop/test/app/log_cvs_files");

        try {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(f, "abc.csv"));
            String s = "Installed";
            fout.write(s.getBytes());
            fout.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which Android version does your device / emulator have?

Comment: @0x0nosugar im using an emulator that is Android 10, API 29

Comment: your PC and AS space is not accessible to an Android application. Android application can only store files to storage of the android device both on real device and emulator

Comment: In order to handle files inside your application please take a look to the official guide: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Comment: ... and if you're having problems specifically with scoped storage for Android 10, there's a series of [blog posts on the Storage Access Framework](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you specified in your Logger class is a path to a directory on your local machine, and not accessible on an Android device. In order to save files on a device, you can read more about opening files inside your app's specific data directory here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#external-access-files